# Incorrect POST-request?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, post, http-post

I'm trying to load an xml via POST-request in Flex:

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest('res/unhasher.xml');
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
loader = new URLLoader();
loader.load(request);
```

But in Firebug I see that my file is loaded through GET.

Request header:

```
GET res/unhasher.xml HTTP/1.1
Host: bla-bla-bla.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:10.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: ru-ru,ru;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

What am I doing wrong? How to make POST requests from Flash/Flex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not actually posting any data, so maybe Flash do a GET instead. Try adding some test data to see if it works:

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest('res/unhasher.xml');
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
var data:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
data.test = "some data";
request.data = data;    
loader = new URLLoader();
loader.load(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your swf in a local/remote server and it should send a POST request. As far as I know, Flash sends GET from local filesystem (either when you open html/swf in a browser via `file://` or from the IDE)

Comment: Nope, this output is from site.